# Replace the $ symbol in String

Tags: java, string

> How to replace all "$$$" present in a String?

I tried

```
story.replaceAll("$$$","\n")
```

This displays a warning: **Anchor $ in unexpected position** and the code fails to work. The code takes the "$" symbol as an anchor for a regular expression. I just need to replace that symbol.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: `story.replaceAll("\\$\\$\\$","\n")`

Comment: replaceAll is for replacing regex.  try using `replace`

Comment: `$` means the end of the `String`

Answer (score 2):

"$" is a special character for regular expressions.

Try the following:

```
    System.out.println(story.replaceAll("\\$\\$\\$", "\n"));
```

We are escaping the "$" character with a '\' in the above code.

Comment: If you base your answer on a comment - at the very least mention the comment writer - https://stackoverflow.com/users/2970947/elliott-frisch

Comment: It wasn't and I didn't see the comments before answering.

Comment: I suggest you take a look in the future. Its the first comment on the OP (and the comment was posted before your answer)

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways you can do this. It depends on what you want to do, and how elegant your solution is:

```java
String replacement = "\n"; // The replacement string

// The first way: 
story.replaceAll("[$]{3}", replacement);

// Second way:
story.replaceAll("\\${3}", replacement);

// Third way:
story.replaceAll("\\$\\$\\$", replacement);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace any special characters (Regular Expression-wise) by escaping that character with a backslash. Since Java-literals use the backslash as escaping-character too, you need to escape the backslash itself.

```
story.replaceAll("\\${3}", something);
```

By using `{3}`behind the `$`, you say, that it should be found exactly three times. Looks a bit more elegant than `"\\$\\$\\$"`.
`something` is thus your replacement, for example `""` or `\n`, depending on what you want.

Answer (score 0):

this will surely work..

```
story.replaceAll("\\$\\$\\$","\n")
```

YOu can do this for any special character.

Comment: This answer was already provided both in the OP comments and as an actual answer before yours......

Comment: @RannLifshitz ,I had typed that answer already and was doing some work and then  I submitted.. so it got delayed. :-)